# Angular 5 console errors happening before data is returned to the page from service , how can this be prevented?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, http-post, angular-services

Problem :   I am seeing several errors in chrome browser F12 dev tools

Around 8 times I am seeing this

```
  ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'CaseDisplayNumber' of undefined
```

HTML template page that is causing this error

```
<span class="header-data">{{caseCaption.CaseDisplayNumber}}</span>
```

under these errors I DO see

```
 this.caseCaption  {CaseDisplayNumber: "CR2017129322000",
```

So it seems to be a timing issue on the call ?

HTML code output LOOKS fine ...

Component

```
    ngOnInit(): void {

              this.pageService.getPageCommonData(this.model) //(this.model)
                        .subscribe(
                        result => {
                                   this.caseCaption = result["data"].CaseCaptionInfo;

                       }
            }
```

Service

```
getPageCommonData(menu: Menu)  {
        return this.http.post(pageCommonData, JSON.stringify(menu), httpOptions)
        .map((response: Response)=> {

            return response;
        })
}
```

Comment: Use `caseCaption?.CaseDisplayNumber`

Comment: You forgot to typecast `this.model`  that you are passing into the getPageCommonData function

Comment: @HarryNinh    oh wow,  we does that work?   can you write up a quick answer   thx  !

Comment: Azzi's is comprehensive, mark it! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the following line of code:

```
<span class="header-data">{{caseCaption.CaseDisplayNumber}}</span>
```

Option 1:

```
<span class="header-data">{{caseCaption?.CaseDisplayNumber}}</span>
```

Option 1 uses `?` called the 'Binary Operator' or 'Elvis Operator'; it returns its first operand if that operand is true. In this case the 'Elvis Operator' notifies the template that an object that needs to be displayed may not be available yet, and allow the template to continue to be rendered.  The object and its values are rendered when the object is available.

[See this article.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_operator)

Option 2:

```
<span *ngIf="caseCaption" class="header-data">{{caseCaption.CaseDisplayNumber}}</span>
```

> From @Brad It's called the Safe Navigation Operator. Very clearly
>   stated in the docs
>   angular.io/guide/template-syntax#expression-operators.

Comment: It's called the Safe Navigation Operator.  Very clearly stated in the docs https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#expression-operators.